# Cannot move file from Ext4 to exFAT if title contains colon (:)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, exfat, file-descriptors

I have a 1TB SSD that I've partitioned in half into Ext4/exFAT. The Ext4 is for better interop with Ubuntu 18.04 (my OS) and the exFAT is for better portability with other systems. I installed `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` for compatibility with Ubuntu.

Orginal description:

> So I have some zip files that I tried unzipping onto the exFAT
>   partition but it's not working. This *ONLY* happens if the zip archive
>   contains a markdown file. My archive contains mp4 files and markdown
>   files. Here's an example: I have an archive.zip containing:
>
> - vid_1.mp4
> - vid_2.mp4
> - vid_3.mp4
> - README.md
>
> ````
> /path/to/vid_1.mp4  extracting: /path/to/vid_2.mp4  extracting:
> /path/to/vid_3.mp4 error:  cannot create /path/to/README.md
>         No such file or directory ```
>
> And in fact everything is unzipped on disc, except for that Markdown
> file at the end.
>
> I've confirmed that if I delete the Markdown file from the archive
> then retry, there are no errors reported.
> ````

Update: ok turns out this was all because the Markdown filename had a colon (:) in the name. If I rename it to remove the colon the transfer works. Had nothing to do with the unzip operation specifically.

Comment: Ok so turns out I was totally off on what the issue was. I said README.md as an example but my actual file had a colon (:) in the name and this turned out to be the issue. Removing the colon allows me to transfer, but this is sort of not the best solution for me since I'm programatically unzipping a large number of archives, and the target isn't *necessarily* an exFAT filesystem. Wonder if there's a good "general solution."

Comment: So what is your *question* now?

Comment: A file should never contain a colon as far as I remember, I don't kown about Unix, but I would/could never create a file with a colon in the title.

Comment: Sorry, the question is, is there a good "automated" way to convert filenames when for example unzipping something so that I don't have to edit the zip file ahead of time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's due to user error, and resolution is not likely to help others.

Comment: You can rename invalid filenames in archive with something like `7z rn 1.7z file:txt file.txt`  Not sure how you'd automate it for this case but see [How to rename a file inside a 7zip archive by CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007304/how-to-rename-a-file-inside-a-7zip-archive-by-cli) or [Rename many files in archive via command line](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/3a1961c0/)

Comment: @lx07 thank you this is helpful!

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik you don't think anyone's gonna have a similar problem ever? I mean you can be like that if you want. You can call it "user error" because I didn't understand the root of the problem at first but anyone unzipping to exFAT a file with invalid exFAT filenames will have this issue.